# 80's TV series where a boy's bedroom becomes a space ship, steering it with his desk lamp

Tags: story-identification, tv

Looking for the name of a children's TV show. Saw it first on TV in the early 80's but possibly produced earlier. Might have been of British origin.

**Plot**:
When a boy fiddles with the lamp on his desk, his 2nd story bedroom detaches from the house and functions like a space ship. He steers the ship with the lamp and adventures ensue.

**Glimpses from the show:**

- Parents can enter the bedroom during flight as if nothing happened, but look semi-transparent.
- Dad at one point scolds boy for messing around with the lamp, straightens it out or replaces the lamp.
- An episode seemed to lift an idea from *Star Trek*'s "Trouble with Tribbles", with creatures that replicate if you try to cut them in half. The episode ends with some kind of barbarian slicing and multiplying the creatures to some beneficial effect. Maybe involving blocking a solar panel.
- Boy meets girl

Comment: Especially if this hasn't been answered yet - was the show live-action or animated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds a lot like a Danish children's show called [**Crash**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0389599/?ref_=nm_flmg_dr_1) from 1984.There were 13 episodes.

> Birger finds out one day, that his room at his parents house can fly
>   into outer space and that he can steer it with his table lamp. On his
>   interstellar journey he meets Iris who flies on a giant hand and he is
>   taken to a huge space station on the edge of a black hole.

You can see all the episodes (in Danish) [here](https://www.dr.dk/bonanza/serie/123/crash).

[image]

Comment: This is the one! The room exterior is as I remember it and both barbarian and "tribbles" present